# Delete lines from file -- awk

Tags: awk

I have a file `file.dat` containing numbers, for example

```
4
6
7
```

I would like to use the numbers of this file to delete lines of another file.

Is there any way to pass this numbers as parameters to awk and delete these lines of another file?

I have this `awk` solution, but do not like it too much...

```
awk 'BEGIN { while( (getline x < "./file.dat" ) > 0 ) a[x]=0; } NR in a { next; }1' /path/to/another/file
```

Can you suggest something more elegant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `NR==FNR` to test which file `awk` is reading:

```
$ awk '{if(NR==FNR)idx[$0];else if(!(FNR in idx))print}' idx.txt data.txt
```

Or

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{idx[$0]; next}; !(FNR in idx)' idx.txt data.txt
```

- put index in `idx.txt`
- put data in `data.txt`

Comment: You can use `next` in your first action to avoid using `NR!=FNR` as the second pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would use sed instead of awk:

```
$ sed $(for i in $(<idx.txt);do echo " -e ${i}d";done) file.txt
```

Comment: `sed 's/.*/&d/' idx.txt | sed -f - file.txt` might be a little less busy.